# Trying to hit EKS cluster from within container

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Summary:  Create EKS cluster.  Attempt to run commands from docker container.  Get error.

Set up.

Follow AWS tutorial on setting up an EKS cluster

1. Create VPC and supporting infra via CFT
2. Create IAM role and policy: myAmazonEKSClusterRole/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy
3. Create EKS cluster via the console logged in as SSO
4. Wait for cluster to be ready
5. From laptop/CLI authenticated as SSO, execute

`aws eks update-kubeconfig --name my-cluster`

6. Execute `kubectl get svc`, get good result
7. Create identity provider in IAM and associate with EKS cluster OpenID connect provider URL
8. Create CNI role and policy: myAmazonEKSCNIRole
9. Associate role to cluster via `aws eks update-addon` command
10. Create node role myAmazonEKSNodeRole and attach policies: AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy and AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly
11. Create key pair in AWS
12. Add Node Group to cluster configured with above role and key pair
13. Wait until node group is active

At this point, if I test with kubectl or helm I can manipulate the cluster.  I’m still authenticating as the SSO user however, and running from my laptop.

Moving on.  I want to manipulate the cluster from within a docker container.  So I continue with the following steps.

EKS cluster is in AWS account B.

1. Create role in AWS account B (RoleInAccountB).  Role has admin access policy in account B.
2. Establish trust between account A and account B so that user in Account A can assume role in account B

On local computer, outside of container (SSO authentication)

3. Download aws-auth-cm.yaml and customize it to add new role:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - groups:
      - system:masters
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<Account B>:role/RoleInAccountB
      username: DOESNTMATTER
```

4. Execute `kubectl apply -f aws-auth-cm.yaml`
5. Watch nodes to ensure they are ready `kubectl get nodes –watch`
6. Verify config `kubectl describe configmap -n kube-system aws-auth`
   Seems fine.
7. SSH to EC2 in Account A
8. Run docker container on EC2 (image has prerequisite dependencies installed such as aws cli, kubectl etc.)

From within the container

9. Assume Account B role
10. Add role to kube config via aws cli

`aws eks update-kubeconfig --name my-cluster --role-arn arn:aws:iam::accountB:role/RoleInAccountB`

11. Execute test to check permission to cluster `kubectl get svc`

Receive error “error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)"

Update: I tried this from the ec2 (outside the container).  I get the same result.

Wondering if the following guidance is what I have to try next.
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/blob/master/README.md

Update 3/19/2021
Still no real solution to the problem.  I found that if I assume a role (console or cli) prior to creating the cluster, then I can assume that role later on in the container/ec2 and manipulate the cluster just fine.  This was expected, but it has become my work around.  Still looking for the correct way to change the cluster permissions to allow some other role (that didn't create the cluster) to perform commands.

Comment: I've added a bonus to this because I'm interested in the answer.

Comment: Is there anything in `~/.kube/config` on the container? It needs to contain authentication data for `kubectl`.

Comment: Yes.  ~/.kube/config contains, among other things

  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-east-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - my-cluster
      - --role
      - arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT B:role/RoleInAccountB
      command: aws

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to understand your current identity context first before running `aws eks update-kubeconfig`, what will be the output of `aws sts get-caller-identity` in Account A before and after step 9?

Another thing worth to try out is to open resulting KUBECONFIG file, look up for the helper command (like `aws-iam-authenticator` or `aws eks get-token`) and execute it directly bypassing `kubectl` authentication handling logic

That's how helpers may look like

```
aws eks get-token --cluster-name my-cluster --role arn:aws:iam::accountB:role/RoleInAccountB
```

or

```
aws-iam-authenticator token -i my-cluster -r arn:aws:iam::accountB:role/RoleInAccountB
```

What will be the output?

Third thing, you may use AWS named profiles to get AWS IAM roles transparently assumed between accounts using `role_arn`/`source_arn` combination.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html#using-aws-iam-roles

Comment: get-caller-identity shows what I would expect.  It references the role in account B being assumed. arn:aws:sts::ACCOUNT B:assumed-role/RoleInAccountB/session

Comment: KUBECONFIG contains aws eks get-token, not aws-iam-authenticator.  Running it on the command line yields what I would expect.  I see a token.  "kind": "ExecCredential", "apiVersion": "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1", "spec": {}, "status": {"expirationTimestamp": "2021-02-25T20:12:36Z", "token": "k8s-aws-v1.a.....

Comment: aws-iam-authenticator is not installed in this container.  I thought about installing it, but not sure if I should go down that road.

Comment: Regarding the use of AWS named profiles.  I am avoiding the use of ~/.aws/credentials or ~/.aws/config as these containers will be fairly ephemeral.  Instead, I am EXPORTing environment variables after calling assume role.  Since aws sts get-caller-identity returns expected result, I think I am safe here.

Comment: As a test I just installed aws-iam-authenticator and tested with it.  I get the token just fine.

Comment: I tried configuring ~/.kube/config with the aws-iam-authenticator and ran a test.  It prompted me for user name. "Please enter Username:"

Comment: thanks for additional info, it helps to understand problem better, you do not have to use both helpers, I provided them to reveal possible options, lets stick to `aws eks get-token` if you have it and forget about the other one

Comment: have you tried to set username to something meaningful as suggested in AWS docs, like `system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}` instead of `DOESNTMATTER`? another thing, you can watch EKS auth logs using CloudWatch logs, worth to check what's going on there as well

Comment: here is a good list of things to check https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-eks-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/troubleshooting.md

Comment: I'm not sure that this is actually a full solution, but it's a good amount of work that helps expose the internals of the problem and helps the user solve it (which is better than a solution in my mind). So, I'm awarding the bounty to it.